# How to add a new column with zero elements to an existing data frame?

Tags: r

I have a pre-existing frame with zero rows and I am trying to add a new column to it using the `<-` operator. However, R keeps ignoring me, probably because the added column also has zero elements. Is there any way to make R add the new column anyway?

```
frame <- data.frame('First' = I(c()))
frame[second.column.name] <- I(c())    # second.column.name is a variable, not actual column name
```

Comment: Or `cbind(frame,x=I(c()))` But What are you tryying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to write a script that deals with corner cases in the simplest way possible. Which, in this case, is to create an empty frame.

Comment: corner case? do you mean bound limits?  I think you should rethink your algorithm to return NULL or to do NOTHING.

Comment: @agstudy Why should I rethink my algorithm? Having an empty frame solves all my problems without needing to branch. It's a typical case of null object pattern.

Comment: I don't know "null object pattern", but it is clear that `is.null(cbind(I(c()),I(c())))` gives FALSE. What I mean that if your end user ar expecting a null object that will get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you use `[[` instead of `[`:

```
frame[["test"]] <- I(c())    
# [1] First test 
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Is there a way to add multiple columns at once?